# setting command alias through python API in gdb

Tags: gdb, gdb-python

I have written a small python script that adds new commands to gdb and for others to use it, they can just source the python file in their `~/.gdbinit`, but I would now like to add some useful aliases to those commands.

Right now I've added a README instruction to add those aliases manually in each user's `~/.gdbinit`, but wanted to know if there's any better way to just add aliases to the new commands in python itself.

Comment: I just do `gdb.execute('alias short-name = long-command-name')`.

Comment: oh wow, that's perfect. I'm not sure why I did not think of that, but thanks a lot